# Problem in pushing a view controller into a navigationController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I need some help. In my Iphone App I have done something like this : 
[image]

.

When Distance is selected, I need to show up another view like this:[image]

Here is how I did it:

**in the header file**

```
@interface RecherchePartenaireViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
{
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    UITableView *tableViewRecherchePartenaire;
    RecherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController *recherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController;
    RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController *recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewRecherchePartenaire;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet  RecherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController *recherchePartenaireTypePartenaireViewController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController *recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController;

@end
```

**in the implementation file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    listData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Type de Partenaire", @"Code postal", @"Ville",@"Distance",@"Nom du Partenaire",@"Audi R8 uniquement",nil];
    NSLog(@"hey %@",listData);
    tableViewRecherchePartenaire.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];   
    navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] init];

    CGRect newRect = navigationController.view.frame;
    newRect.size.height -= [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.origin.y;
    [navigationController.view setFrame:newRect];
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

When the third row of the table is selected I do this:

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if (indexPath.row==3){
            NSLog(@"RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController..."); 
            recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController = [[RecherchePartenaireDistanceViewController alloc]  init];
          recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController.recherchePartenaireViewController=self;

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController animated:YES];

        }

    }
```

Please tell me where am I going wrong cause this doesn't seem to work.Thank you.

Comment: I dont see navigation controller in parent object...

Comment: If I put this : [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view]; in viewDidLoad, the tableview is unselected...and on tableview I have some textfields that I want to change, and with this line, the keyboard doesn't appear...so, how should I do?

Comment: You can push in such way: `[self presentModalViewController: recherchePartenaireDistanceViewController animated:YES];`

Comment: I this way the view come from down. ..I want the view to appear from right to left, and not from down to up..How can I do this?

Comment: Check `UIModalTransitionStyle modalTransitionStyle`... But there are no such style.

Comment: The only way is to add navigationController to your parent view

Comment: But how can I do to work and navigationController and tableview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach would be to have a navigationController object with the first tableView as its rootViewController. On the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method proceed as you do right now. That will push the detailViewController. And in your rootViewController, hide the navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

*Moving from comments to here.*

You should add navigation controller to your root view or you won't be able to call method `pushViewConroller:`.

For example, you can create root view controller in such manner:

```
RootViewController *controller = [[RootViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
[controller release];
```

You can push navigation controller, for example, in a such way:

```
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```